# Getting Error when using Android YouTube Video Player 'com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer:core:10.0.5' after removing JCenter()

Tags: android, android-studio, jcenter, youtubeplayer

This is the error while building the gradle.

```
[![Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer:core:10.0.5.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/pierfrancescosoffritti/androidyoutubeplayer/core/10.0.5/core-10.0.5.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/pierfrancescosoffritti/androidyoutubeplayer/core/10.0.5/core-10.0.5.pom
     Required by:
         project :app

Possible solution:
 - Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html
```

[image]

Comment: AFAIK, some libraries are not included in `mavenCentral()` so you may have to look for another library. I'd assume you already have `mavenCentral()` since it's included by default for recent AS versions.

Answer (score 1):

did you add mavenCentral()?please replace mavenCentral() instead of jcenter

Answer (score 0):

The library is not maintained if you look at the repo on [github](https://github.com/PierfrancescoSoffritti/android-youtube-player) the last commit was on *Nov 11, 2019*. So the maintainer has probably not published the library on `mavenCentral`. I suggest you download or clone the repo from Github and use it as a module in your project, or generate a `jar` or `aar` and use it as a locale library.

Comment: but  how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Add implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"]) to your app level module dependency

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: That's not going to work.  They're not trying to find a .jar dependency, they're trying to download one off Maven.